# ulogd2.service doesn't work with Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10

ulogd2.service doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 19.10.

When I do `ls /run/ulog/ulogd.pid` it finds nothing.
I think the file can't be generated.

When I do `ls -lt /run` it shows the correct access rights:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 ulog    ulog      40 Feb 16 17:32 ulog


Feb 16 17:32:28 stag-1 ulogd[7074]: registering plugin `JSON'
Feb 16 17:32:28 stag-1 ulogd[7074]: building new pluginstance stack: 'ct1:NFCT,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTFLOW,emunfct1:LOGEMU'
Feb 16 17:32:28 stag-1 ulogd[7074]: can't find requested plugin NFCT
Feb 16 17:32:28 stag-1 ulogd[7074]: building new pluginstance stack: 'ct2:NFCT,ip2str1:IP2STR,jsonnfct1:JSON'
Feb 16 17:32:28 stag-1 ulogd[7074]: can't find requested plugin NFCT
Feb 16 17:32:28 stag-1 ulogd[7074]: not even a single working plugin stack
Feb 16 17:32:28 stag-1 systemd[1]: ulogd2.service: Can't open PID file /run/ulog/ulogd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Feb 16 17:32:28 stag-1 systemd[1]: ulogd2.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit ulogd2.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'protocol'.
Feb 16 17:32:28 stag-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Netfilter Userspace Logging Daemon.
-- Subject: A start job for unit ulogd2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit ulogd2.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 26836 and the job result is failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. The error message wasn't clear to me.
ulogd2 has most plugins commented out by default in Ubuntu 19.10. (Unlike 18.04).

I had to remove # (comment-in) the following four to make it work correctly.  It will then automatically create that pid file. It is not about permissions as I first thought.

```
plugin="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ulogd/ulogd_inpflow_NFCT.so"
plugin="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ulogd/ulogd_filter_IP2STR.so"
plugin="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ulogd/ulogd_filter_PRINTFLOW.so"
plugin="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ulogd/ulogd_output_LOGEMU.so"
```